# Service worker не обрабатывает событие fetch

Tags: javascript, service-worker

столкнулся с проблемой что service worker не обрабатывает событие fetch. События install и activate срабатывают , fetch никак не ловится, ни в первый раз, ни после перезагрузок , ни на каких запросах (ресурсы или апи) . Приложение сделано через CRA , service worker находится в папке public. После билда хранится в самом корне проекта , так что область видимости для перехвата распространяется на весь проект. Ниже прикреплены скрины , показывающие статус, выводы консоли и код сервис воркера. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?
[image: код сервис воркера]

```
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    console.log('EVENT INSTALL =>', event);
    event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    console.log('ACTIVATE =>', event);
    event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    console.log('FETCH =>', event);
});
```

[image: вывод в консоль]
[image: статус сервис воркера]

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Исправьте вопрос, чтобы код в текстовом формате, для этого нажмите [edit] под самим вопросом

Answer (score 0):

В данной ситуацией проблемой было , установленный путь в homepage в package.json (отличным от корня) что перенаправляло область отслеживания service-worker , запросов, по тому пути. Исправление homepage в данной ситуации , решило проблему.